# HTML don't use my css in Spring application

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

As follows in my code i have referenced my css from html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/eja.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

and i have this structure

[image]

Application class doesnt have anything extra, just standard generated application class.

Comment: i think im adding my css wrong. but where else should i add it? Because when i open index.html from intellij it opens with css loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Seems i need to write /css/eja.css even if it is not existing in this folder.
Cause css resources loaded to /css/** and not to other path.